# How to get Google contact labels?

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api

I'm using [this API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference) to get user's contacts.
I would get the label associated to a contact, but I can't find it in the documentation.
I'm not talking about label property, like `<gContact:relation label="drinking buddy">Marvin</gContact:relation>` but this kind of label :

[image: Label Image]

If someone could tell me where to find this label.

Comment: I dont think the api supports that and nether does the people api

Comment: Not sure, but it seems to be the Google Groups. `gContact:groupMembershipInfo`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Labels" = "[Contact Groups](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#working_with_contact_groups)"

Call the groups feed (https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/default/full?v=3) and then match the group ID's to the gContact:groupMemershipInfo from the contacts.

Comment: You're right, I just found it :D Thanks for your answer